# How do I place two JSX elements next to each other?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, core-ui

I cannot figure out how to put these elements next to each other using inline styles.

Right now, the buttons and drop down are all stacked on top of each other.
I would like it to be

```
Test Run Information                     | Previous | Show 25 | Next |
```

all within the same row.

I am using React with CoreUI. Here is the CardHeader below, along with a screenshot

```
<CardHeader style={{alignItems:"center"}}>

<h5 style={{float:"left",marginTop:10}}> {this.props.header} </h5>
<nav style={{float:"right",marginTop:10}}>
    <ul class="pagination" >
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={() => {this.prevPage()}}>Previous</a></li>
    </ul>
    <Input type="select" name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" bsSize="sm"  >
    <option key="Default" value=''>Show 25</option>
    </Input>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={() => {this.nextPage()}}>Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</CardHeader>
```

[Current hideous layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3xEX.png)

There is way too much extra space and misalignment. I would like everything in line.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to wrap those 3 elements within a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) parent container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

And on your component,

```
<CardHeader style={{alignItems:"center"}}>

<h5 style={{float:"left",marginTop:10}}> {this.props.header} </h5>
<nav style={{float:"right",marginTop:10}}>
<div className="container">
  <ul class="pagination" >
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={() => {this.prevPage()}}>Previous</a></li>
  </ul>
  <Input type="select" name="selectSm" id="SelectLm" bsSize="sm"  >
  <option key="Default" value=''>Show 25</option>
  </Input>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={() => {this.nextPage()}}>Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
</CardHeader>
```

Comment: Thank you, added this to my main CSS and used <nav className="nav-container"/>

Comment: How would I make each item the same height? The drop down is different from the buttons

Comment: Hmm.. Have you tried toggling the CSS properties of the buttons? And set them as the same value?

Answer (score 0):

Try styling them:

```
display: inline
```